# Rendering on top of Adobe AIR

Tags: air, media, multimedia

My co-worker posted a question on his [blog](http://rob.crabapples.net/2009/01/rendering-on-top-of-adobe-air.htm) . He is referring to rendering an MPEG-4 stream in adobe air. He wants to know basically two things.

> Are there any technical articles
>   floating around that...
>
> 1. Describe how AIR renders.
> 2. Describes a technique for painting
>      on an AIR surface in a way that
>      doesn't effect AIR performance?

Does SO Community have answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an AIR app is a container that loads a swf or html / javascript content, i think the question is: "How flash renders". So i'll suggest to read something about the flv video codecs.